# Wordpress - Identifying Page Name

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Have implemented a site in wordpress with 5 static pages besides the usual blog pages that are accesible through the nav menu. Now each of the page has its own jquery animations.

**Since I want to write the animations code for all pages in a single file I want to get the page name in javascript and then switch to the proper animation function for that page. How to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to your Wordpress template, you may output the current page's ID with the `the_ID()` template function: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID

If you put this in your <head>, you could access the page ID in JavaScript afterwards:

```
<script>
var pageId = <?php the_ID(); ?>;
</script>
```

An alternative: The default theme Twenty Ten assigns a class "page-id-xx" to the <body> element by default. If your current theme does something similar, you could look for this class like this:

```
if ($('body').hasClass('page-id-xx')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alert( document.URL );  it will tell you current url . and according to ypur requirement you can made changes.

see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-46183437)

Comment: You can also use window.location.href